# Group array of objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

```
const readings = [
  { location: { lat: '21.4', lng: '23.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'1' },
  { location: { lat: '22.4', lng: '25.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'2' },
  {  location: { lat: '21.4', lng: '23.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'3' },
  { location: { lat: '22.4', lng: '25.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'2' },
  { location: { lat: '28.4', lng: '21.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'5' },
];
```

I want to group the below array of objects by location property.

The expected result is an array of objects
with location and points(array of objects which have the same location).

Group array of objects using lodash or array reduce method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Answer (score 1):

The `_.groupBy()` function accepts a callback that defines the key to group by. You can concatenate the `lat` and `lng` using a template string, and use that as the key.

```js
const readings = [{"location":{"lat":"21.4","lng":"23.5"},"vehicle":"sdkhf","id":"1"},{"location":{"lat":"22.4","lng":"25.5"},"vehicle":"sdkhf","id":"2"},{"location":{"lat":"21.4","lng":"23.5"},"vehicle":"sdkhf","id":"3"},{"location":{"lat":"22.4","lng":"25.5"},"vehicle":"sdkhf","id":"2"},{"location":{"lat":"28.4","lng":"21.5"},"vehicle":"sdkhf","id":"5"}];

const result = _.groupBy(readings, ({ location: { lat, lng} }) => `${lat}-${lng}`);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce` to group `readings` by `location` and then transform the resulting map to an `array` of objects having location as `key` and points list as `value`:

```js
const readings = [
  { location: { lat: '21.4', lng: '23.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'1' },
  { location: { lat: '22.4', lng: '25.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'2' },
  {  location: { lat: '21.4', lng: '23.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'3' },
  { location: { lat: '22.4', lng: '25.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'2' },
  { location: { lat: '28.4', lng: '21.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'5' },
];

//group by location
let res = _.reduce(readings, (acc,item) => {
  const { location: { lat, lng } } = item;
  const key = `${lat}-${lng}`;
  const prev = acc[key];
  if(!prev) acc[key] = [item];
  else acc[key].push(item);
  return acc;
}, {});
//transform to array of objects location-points
res = _.map(_.entries(res), ([location,points]) => ({ [location]: points }));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lodash groupBy will make it easier for u, just pass a comparison function, for example:

```
import _ from "lodash";

const readings= [
  {
      location: {
          lat: '21.4',
          lng: '23.5'
      },
      vehicle: 'sdkhf',
      id:'1'
  },
  {
      location: {
          lat: '22.4',
          lng: '25.5'
      },
      vehicle: 'sdkhf',
      id:'2'
  },
  {
      location: {
          lat: '21.4',
          lng: '23.5'
      },
      vehicle: 'sdkhf',
      id:'3'
  },
  {
      location: {
          lat: '22.4',
          lng: '25.5'
      },
      vehicle: 'sdkhf',
      id:'2'
  },
  {
      location: {
          lat: '28.4',
          lng: '21.5'
      },
      vehicle: 'sdkhf',
      id:'5'
  },
]

const getLocation = ({ location }) => `${location.lat}/${location.lng}`
const objGrouped = _.groupBy(readings, getLocation)
const arrayGrouped = Object.values(objGrouped)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `#array.reduce` method**

Although other answers look good with `lodash`, you can easily achieve it by using `.reduce()`.

The key point here is getting `key` with the format.

```
const key = `lat.${curr.location.lat}-lng.${curr.location.lng}`
```

Or any format as you like. As long as it based on `location.lat & location.lng` along with the key should be a `string` instead of `object`.

```js
const readings = [
  { location: { lat: '21.4', lng: '23.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'1' },
  { location: { lat: '22.4', lng: '25.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'2' },
  {  location: { lat: '21.4', lng: '23.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'3' },
  { location: { lat: '22.4', lng: '25.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'2' },
  { location: { lat: '28.4', lng: '21.5' }, vehicle: 'sdkhf', id:'5' },
];

var result = readings.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const key = `lat.${curr.location.lat}-lng.${curr.location.lng}`
    acc[key] ??= {[key]: []};
    acc[key][key].push(curr);

    return acc;
  }, {})

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: @Naveen Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help ^^!